# How to prove the existence of matrix $E$ such that $\|E\|_F=\frac{\|u\|_2}{\|v\|_2}$?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

$A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, given $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ and $u\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $u\neq 0$ and $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of matrix $A$. Prove that: we can choose a matrix $E$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
\|E\|_F=\frac{\|u\|_2}{\|v\|_2},
\end{align*}
such that $v=(\lambda I-A)^{-1}u$ is an eigenvector of matrix $A+E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E=uv^+=uv^T/\|v\|_2^2$ then $(A+E)v=Av+uv^+v=Av+u$. So if $u=(\lambda I-A)v$, then $(A+E)v=Av+u=Av+(\lambda I-A)v=\lambda v$. We have $\|E\|_F=\|u\|_2\|v^+\|_2=\|u\|_2/\|v\|_2$.